# Convert java interface to Json

Tags: java, json, interface, gson, jemos-podam

I have an interface called `CreditCardResource` and I want to generate a json from that.

```
public interface CreditCardResource {
    ....
}
```

I tried generating json for `CreditCardResouce.class` with podam and gson.

Podam generates an error as below:

```
PodamFactoryImpl [WARN] Cannot instantiate an interface or abstract class. Returning null.
```

With Gson, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class
```

Is it possible to convert `CreditCardResource.class` to json?

Comment: so you can not jsonify an interface,  Try the concreate class.

Comment: I am getting another error when I try this with the concrete class: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)

Comment: better show your code then.

Comment: You simply can not, JSON is as name suggests `JavaScript Object Notation` and Interface can not be instantiated. You can try by implementing a class for it though.

Comment: You can not convert a class or interface to JSON. Only an object can be converted to JSON. So something is missing in the question.

Comment: I could convert the concrete class to JSON using Jackson and I could insert dummy values into the JSON using Podam Factory. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

A json is a particular type of structured string, which can be used (among other things) to represent the state of POJOs. An interface is just a contract, and hence converting it to JSON doesn't really make sense. What you might want to do instead is define a method in the interface that returns the JSON representation of the concrete objects created using that interface. Something like (using Gson):

```
public interface Something {
    String toJson();
}
```

Now, any implementing class would be required to implement this method, as below:

```
public class SomethingImpl implements Something {
   public String toJson() {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       return gson.toJson(this);
   }
}
```